# How to wait my thread up to the latitude and longitude greater than zero

Tags: android, multithreading, android-location

In my android app there is a splash screen which checks the gps and get the latitude and longitude. When the user just turn on the gps and run my app it will not wait for the location fix. The app just show an error dialog and quitting. So I inserted some code to wait the execution up to the latitude and longitude greater than zero. But this is not working. It just only waiting and waiting. Any help will be appreciated.

**this is my code**

```
    if(gps.getLatitude()==0.0&&gps.getLongitude()==0.0){
    while(gps.getLatitude()>0.0&&gps.getLongitude()>0.0){
    try {
    new Thread() {
     public void run() {
       try{
     // calling background Async task to load Google Places
     new LoadPlaces().execute();
     } 
        catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("inside thread", e.getMessage());
    }
                                                                       }
   }.wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }
    }
   else{
 // calling background Async task to load Google Places
 new LoadPlaces().execute();
   }
```

Comment: Lat and lng can be negative or positive maybe !(gps.getlatitude==0)  like that in while, what are you waiting for coordinates from gps?

Comment: If lat and lng are both positive your while loop will keep executing and waiting

Comment: if the gps is just turned on the location value is null so that latitude and longitude value will be 0.0 because it can't be null its type is double

Comment: @agen451 you are loading asynctask inside a thread. pls check the link @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. I had also commented on your previous question which looked similar

Comment: @Raghunandan, Since he didn't explicitly start the thread. His runnable code will run in the same existing thread.

Comment: @ahen451, In order wake thread after wait(), you should call notify()

Comment: @Anirudh First of all why is the need to put the asynctask in a runnable thread. asynctask doinbackground runs in the background thread.

Comment: @agen451 i suggest you post your logcat details of the crash.

Comment: @Raghunandan, I agrre with you. I was just pointing that it wasn't the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Raghunandan: Now there is no crash i caught that exception with a try-catch and an alert-dialog inside it to exit from the app

Comment: @Raghunandan:http://pastie.org/7972327

Comment: @Raghunandan:This is my entire class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UI thread should never perform a blocking call like `Thread.wait()`: doing that will freeze the entire thread, resulting in an Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog (or a deadlock, or termination). Read the Android developer guides about [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), and [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html): it's important to understand what they cover, before embarking on writing multithreading code.

Then, read through the [Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) guide: specifically [Receiving Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). This explains how to get the last known location, if any, and implement a `LocationListener` to receive updates.

Comment: if i use another asynctask inside this if block to retrieve the location which is greater than 0 will it be better?

Comment: It does not matter how many `AsyncTask`s you use: all that matters is that you don't block inside the UI thread waiting for any of them. In this case, you probably don't want to start any extra tasks: the location service is already a separate process. What you'll want to do is create and register a `LocationListener`, as described in those guides, to receive callbacks and update your UI (for example, by closing the splash screen).

Answer (score -1):

You may use LocationListener.onLocationChanged for watching location changes